# Checking if Firebase Services are available

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase services (Auth, Database etc). Is there anyway to find out when firebase services are down and to notify the user ? I have tried going through firebase documentation and searched the internet and have not found any.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current status on this [dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

You could call the data from this [link](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents.json). That gives you the latest incidents for the Firebase services in `json` format. [Here](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents.schema.json) is the `shema` for it.

You could get the data in regular intervals and check if new items arrive for the service you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, Although i don't need it anymore figured out an error code in Firebase for this purpose.